# how can I find the number of epochs for which keras model was trained?

Tags: r, keras

How can I find the number of epochs for which keras model was trained?

1. I use [callback_early_stopping()](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/callback_early_stopping.html) to stop the training early to avoid overfitting.
2. I have been using [callback_csv_logger()](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/callback_csv_logger.html) to log training performances. But sometimes, I train
   100s of keras models and it does not make sense to log entire training just to know the number of epochs for which each model.

```
library(keras)
library(kerasR)
library(tidyverse)


# Data
x = matrix(data = runif(30000), nrow = 10000, ncol = 3)
y = ifelse(rowSums(x) > 1.5 + runif(10000), 1, 0)
y = to_categorical(y)

# keras model
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%   
  layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu", input_shape = ncol(x)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = ncol(y), activation = "softmax")

model %>%
  compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", 
          optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(), 
          metrics = "accuracy")

model %>% 
  fit(x, y, 
      epochs = 1000,
      batch_size = 128,
      validation_split = 0.2, 
      callbacks = callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", patience = 5),
      verbose = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the number of epochs (whetevere you want) you can use a callback.
Here's an example:

```
class print_log_Callback(Callback):
  def __init__(self, logpath, steps):
    self.logpath = logpath
    self.losslst = np.zeros(steps)

  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self.losslst[batch] = logs["loss"]
    with open(logpath, 'a') as writefile:
      with redirect_stdout(writefile):
        print("For batch {}, loss is {:7.2f}.".format(batch, logs["loss"]))
        writefile.write("\n")

  def on_test_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    with open(logpath, 'a') as writefile:
      with redirect_stdout(writefile):
        print("For batch {}, val_loss is {:7.2f}.".format(batch, logs["loss"]))
        writefile.write("\n")

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    with open(logpath, 'a') as writefile:
      with redirect_stdout(writefile):
        print("The val_loss  for epoch {} is {:7.2f}.".format(epoch, logs['val_loss']))
        writefile.write("\n")
        print("The mean train loss is: ", np.mean(self.losslst))
        writefile.write("\n")
        writefile.write("\n")

    self.losslst = np.zeros(steps)
```

you call it like this:

```
print_log_Callback(logpath=logpath, steps=int(steps))
```

where logpath is the path of the text file where you are writing the code and steps is the number of steps.

This callback basically prints on a text file the entire history of the network.

loss after every batch and after every epoch end.

If you need only the epoch you could use just the method `on_epoch_end` and remove everything else.

If you want to print the loss after every epoch you can use this modified version:

```
class print_log_Callback(Callback):
  def __init__(self, logpath, steps):
    self.logpath = logpath
    self.losslst = np.zeros(steps)

  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self.losslst[batch] = logs["loss"]

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    with open(logpath, 'a') as writefile:
      with redirect_stdout(writefile):
        print("The val_loss  for epoch {} is {:7.2f}.".format(epoch, logs['val_loss']))
        writefile.write("\n")
        print("The mean train loss is: ", np.mean(self.losslst))
        writefile.write("\n")
        writefile.write("\n")

    self.losslst = np.zeros(steps)
```

you can modify this callback to print also the metric: just print `logs["accuracy"]` for example.

Comment: the main point is that with a custom callback you can print the actual epoch number with the variable ```epoch``` and do other stuff in a more flexible way

Answer (score 1):

I use tensorflow keras in python however, my initial search would be in the history that holds all information from the relevant logging from the model after fitting (loss, validation loss, accuracy, F1 etc)

I suspect this is the same in R -

as per: https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/training_visualization.html

simply assign a history variable to your model fit call like:

```
history <- model %>% 
  fit(x, y, 
      epochs = 1000,
      batch_size = 128,
      validation_split = 0.2, 
      callbacks = callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", patience = 5),
      verbose = 1)
```

convert history to dataframe (`as.data.frame(history)`) within which you will find your metrics - the length of the metrics are the same as the number of epochs the model was trained on

Comment: Thank you, I do something very similar with `callbacks_csv_logger()`. The length the training log is the number of epochs. Is there a way to directly save the number of epochs

Comment: Not that I am aware of (even in python, I am not sure there is a direct way of accessing this without querying the length of the metrics)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it doesn't help much with the answer but for what it's worth:

Assuming the fitting uses a given `batch_size` and no `EarlyStopping` callback, one could infer the number of trained epochs in Python:

```
np.ceil(model.optimizer.iterations.numpy() / np.ceil(len(X_train) / batch_size))
```

[Kera's github reference](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1766#issuecomment-1158624546)